# How comma (,) works in a for loop between two expressions in conditional part

Tags: c++, loops, initialization

In the for loop at initialization part  you can declare and initialize many variables  as you like but ofcourse they have to be same type.In conditional part you can apply any expressional statements like AND(&&),OR(||),>,<,== etc.
but(,) is not a expression .How it works here
just a=1,2,3,4,5,6 and b=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
and a<6,b<9 returns a=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9=b

```
for(int a=1,b=1,c=2,d=5;a<4,b<10;a++,b++)//initialize variables and using , between expression
{
    cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
}
```

Comment: outside of a decleration statement or a function parameter list a comma is the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Comment: Outside of variable declarations, the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) is used to evaluate a series of expressions and then return the result of the last expression.

Comment: It doesn't actually work like or, it's a different operator.

Comment: Nope, I just tested it, it does not behave as you say. Comma inside of `for` condition works in a same way as in any other expression. `(a, b) == b`.

Comment: That thing is just horrible anyway:(

Comment: When you have to declare and initialize variabes they must have to same type because for different types declaration needs more ; in intialization part that is not accepted

Comment: you only can initialise different variables of different types but do not declare and initialise  different types of  variables in initialization part of for loop  because it occupies more (;) in for loops that is avoided.

Answer (score 12):

Because...that's not really how things work at all.

The comma operator evaluates and discards its left operand (so in most cases its left operand will have side effects). After the left operand is evaluated (and any side effects from it have happened), the right operand is evaluate. The value yielded from this is the value of the right operand.

Comment: Exactly.  If the comma was operating like OR, it would return true if the first condition was true - it doesn't, it just returns the value of the second condition.

Answer (score 9):

Actually it's not or, the behavior of comma operator can be described as:

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator
>   (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its
>   first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second
>   operand and returns this value (and type).

From wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

So only the result of `k<10` taken into the account.